# rabbitmq-shovel amqps connection handshake failure

Tags: ssl, tls, rabbitmq, amqp

I fail to setup a rabbitmq shovel over amqps. 
The same shovel works fine over amqp.

my (edited) uri:

```
amqps://un:pw@myhost.example.com:5679?cacertfile=/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cacert.crt&certfile=/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt&keyfile=/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key&verify=verify_peer
```

the error in the stunnel log:

```
SSL_accept: 14094410: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

and the shovel status is

{{badmatch,{error,{tls_alert,"handshake failure"}}}

Connecting via openssl from the shell works:

```
openssl s_client -connect myhost.example.com:5679 -cert /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt -key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cacert.crt
```

returns

```
Negotiated TLSv1/SSLv3 ciphersuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256-bit encryption)
```

My rabbitmq.config:

```
[
  {kernel, [

  ]},
  {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1' ]}]},
  {rabbit, [
    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cacert.crt"},
                    {certfile,"/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt"},
                    {keyfile,"/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key"},
                    {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']},
                    {depth, 2},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},
    {tcp_listen_options, [binary, {packet,raw},
                                  {reuseaddr,true},
                                  {backlog,128},
                                  {nodelay,true},
                                  {exit_on_close,false},
                                  {keepalive,false}]},

    {default_user, <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass, <<"guest">>},
    {heartbeat, 580}
  ]}
]
```

Comment: Why have you disabled TLSv1? Your log from the openssl-call shows, that TLSv1 or SSL3 was used, but it's forbidden for rabbitmq.

Comment: The openssl call is over TLSv1.2 - from the log:


`SSL handshake has read 6051 bytes and written 431 bytes

---

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

Server public key is 2048 bit

Secure Renegotiation IS supported

Compression: NONE

Expansion: NONE

SSL-Session:

    Protocol  : TLSv1.2

    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`


I disabled TLSv1 because it's vulnerable to a variation of the poodle attack. I had same results with TLSv1 enabled. If I add the  -tls1_2 flag  the log still says 

`New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`